# How to remove string in double brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to know how can I remove the string in double brackets & including brackets. Here's an example

```
var str="(C84) [Yayui (shirogisu)] 1 Day with the Commodore";
var n = str.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/g, '')
alert(n);
```

So far it only removed single brackets but not the one with brackets inside another bracket. The final output should look like this:

```
1 Day with the Commodore
```

How can I remove the string in any type of brackets such as {,},[,],(,)
Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/aPa25/

Comment: What do you mean by double brackets?

Comment: like brackets inside another bracket like [Yayui (shirogisu)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should  work as the replace regex.  It looks individually for each of the bracket types.

```
\s*(?:\[[^[]+]|\([^)]+\)|{[^}]+})\s*
```

Edit:  I think the "nesting order" needs to be the same as in the regex, so it may require re-ordering of the alternation if what I have is wrong.  However, it does work on your examples.

Comment: Hmm. If you thought it didn't work, why mark it as the answer?  In any event, looking at your fiddle link, it seems you just copied the regex, and did not add the javascript specific /'s and arguments.  Do that and it should work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by double brackets, but to remove all the stuff in both parens and square braces you could use

```
str.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/g, '').replace(/\s*\[.*\]\s*/g, '')
```

The first `replace` removes everything in parentheses, the second removes everything in square braces.

Additionally, if you know the form of your input is always going to be like that, i.e. a parenthetical part followed by a square braced part, you could just do:

```
str.replace(/^\s*\(\w+\)\s*\[.*\]\s*/, '')
```

It's less general but might be more robust if that assumption is true.

EDIT: Given that there can be other paren and square braces later in the text that you want to keep, try:

```
str.replace(/\s*\([^)]*\)\s*/g, '').replace(/\s*\[[^\]]*\]\s*/g, '')
```

If you say there can be square braces nested within the first square braces, I will say that, mathematically, you will require a more powerful theoretical machine than a finite state machine (regex).

Comment: I just tried and it works with the current string but it doesn't work with other strings. Here's my example http://jsfiddle.net/aPa25/ the output gave {pesu} when it should of been "Midsummer Letty-san"

Comment: It would help to know the constraints of the dataset you're working with, especially if you are bound to using regexes for the solution.

Comment: I tried your last code and it seems to only remove the first part of brackets but not the brackets after the word. The output gave: Midsummer Letty-san (Touhou Project) [English] {pesu} 
Here's more example data sets you could use http://pastebin.com/aBRt9KDv

Comment: I just updated the final regex. The curly brace removal is left to you as an exercise, because I suspect I'm helping you with a homework assignment and thereby crippling you.